# Total variation distance between pairs when one variable is independent of the rest

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\Delta(\cdot, \cdot)$ denote total variation distance. Let $X, Y, U, V$ be random variables, where $U$ is independent of $(X, Y, V)$. Does this imply $\Delta((X, Y), (U, Y)) \leq \Delta((X, Y), (U, V))$? For simplicity, assume all the random variables are discrete.

Surely there is a simple proof or a simple counterexample, but so far I can't find either. If we drop the independence assumption, it's easy to find counterexamples, e.g., sample $A \in \{0, 1\}$ uniformly at random and let $X = Y = A$ and $U = V = 1 - A$.

Comment: I don't think this question is well-posed. Total variation distance is about *probability distributions*, not random variables -- that is, you can't impose (in)dependence structures between the two arguments. It's a metric between the *distributions* of $(X,Y)$ and $(U,Y)$, and those distributions don't change if I replace say $(X,Y)$ by anything with the same distribution -- say $(X',Y')$.

Comment: @ClementC. I hear what you're saying, but the problem is well-posed. For two random variables $A$ and $B$, $\Delta(A, B)$ is the total variation distance between the distribution of $A$ and the distribution of $B$. In the original question, I said to assume $U$ is independent of $(X, Y, V)$. It would be equivalent to assume $U$ is independent of $Y$ and of $V$, since as you're pointing out, all that matters is independence *within* each argument of $\Delta$.

Comment: Well, not quite, since then why is the dependence structure between $U$ and $X$ relevant?

Comment: The dependence structure between $U$ and $X$ is not relevant. That's what I was saying in my previous comment: rather than assuming that $U$ is independent of $(X, Y, V)$, it is equivalent to merely assume that $U$ is independent of $Y$ and of $V$.

Comment: I read your previous comment too quickly :) What I mean is that it's not even the "same" U and Y there.... "$U$ is independent of $Y$" in the first $(U,Y)$, but that's not the same "realization" of $Y$ as in the first argument $(X,Y)$ -- it's all about the distributions of $(X,Y)$ and $(U,Y)$, considered separately. Using the same letters and considering TV of r.v.'s instead of distributions leads to ambiguity.

Comment: So basically, the way I can interpret your question (identifying probability distributions with pmfs) is "Let $p$ be a probability distribution on some discrete space $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$, with marginals $p_X$ and $p_Y$; and let $u,v$ be two probability distributions on $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ respectively. Is it always the case that $$\Delta(p, u\otimes p_Y) \leq\Delta(p, u\otimes v)$$?" Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to remove some notational ambiguity I am rephrasing your question as

> Let $p$ be a probability distribution on some discrete space $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$, with marginals $p_X$ and $p_Y$; and let $u,v$ be two probability distributions on $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ respectively. Is it always the case that $\Delta(p, u\otimes p_Y) \leq\Delta(p, u\otimes v)$
> ?

The answer is *no*. Take for instance $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{Y}=\{0,1\}$, and $p,u,v$ defined as follows:
$$
p(0,0) = p(1,1)=0, \quad p(0,1)=p(1,0)=\frac{1}{2}
$$
and
$$
u(0)=\frac{1}{10}, \;u(1)=\frac{9}{10} \qquad\text{and}\qquad v(0)=\frac{9}{10}, \;v(1)=\frac{1}{10}
$$
Note that the marginal $p_Y$ of $p$ is uniform on $\{0,1\}$.

Then, we can compute
$$
2\Delta(p, u\otimes p_Y) = |\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{2}-0|+|\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}|+|\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}|+|\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{2}-0|=1
$$
while
$$
2\Delta(p, u\otimes v) = |\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10}-0|+|\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{2}|+|\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10}-\frac{1}{2}|+|\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}-0|=\frac{98}{100}
$$
so $\boxed{\Delta(p, u\otimes p_Y) > \Delta(p, u\otimes v)}$.

Comment: Another nice example: Let $p(1,0)=u(1)=3/4$, $p(0,1)=u(0)=1/4$, $v(0)=1$ and the rest 0. Then $\Delta(p,u\otimes v)=1/2$ and $\Delta(p,u\otimes p_Y)=3/4$.

Comment: Nice one! Also, I have to check, but if I recall correctly my computation, with my choice of $p$ any $u=(a,1-a)$ and $v=(b,1-b)$ with $0<a\leq1/2$ and $1/2\leq b<1$ would give a counterexample. I picked $a=1/10$ and $b=9/10$
 arbitrarily, but presumably other choices may give nicer values of TV.